# Resize android datepicker control

Tags: android, android-widget, android-controls

How can one resize the initial size of android datepicker control to be smaller or bigger. Is there only way to reimplement it?

Answer (score 7):

I haven't been able to figure out a way to resize it, but have seen implementations where they utilize the DatePicker as a dialog.  The date is rendered as TextView with an edit button, which launches the DatePicker dialog.  It saves screen real estate when not editing...

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html

Answer (score 3):

To resize the datepicker go the xml and and add `android:scaleX` and `android:scaleY` to the appropriate size you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with weight sum inside a restricted container (such as by the screen size or forced padding).
I've posted in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33702510/2584698) how did it work for me quite well

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
android:scaleX=""
android:scaleY=""
```

to your XML and change the size of `DatePicker`