# Make DatePicker and TimePicker smaller

Tags: android

Is there any way to make smaller DatePicker and TimePicker (but to be visible all parts ) in Android ? I tried to set layout_width="130dp" but then DatePicker isn't visible, just left upper corner.

Comment: you can try with this: http://andmobidev.blogspot.com/2010/01/setting-width-of-view-using-percentage.html

Comment: Hey there - I am not sure this is gonna help you, but I also found the original TimePicker to be quite clunky, hence I made my own one :) check out my [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921543/android-looking-for-different-timepicker-style) for more information. The TimePicker I made is about half the size of the original one - so it definitely is smaller :).

Comment: checkout my solution (and hopefully accept it because this page was the first result in my google feed and it took me hours to fix it)

Comment: Follow this answer, it work like charm!
http://stackoverflow.com/a/34523787/1983018

Answer (score 19):

Use properties follow:

Example smaller 80% original

```
android:scaleY="0.8" 
android:scaleX="0.8"
```

Comment: [Note: requires API level 11 (Android 3.0)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setScaleX(float)).

Comment: It still occupies the same space (the datepicker is smaller, but have a big margin and useless space around)
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: maybe you have to custom your datepicker. ex: https://github.com/luminousman/DatePicker

Comment: Allan Ramírez is right, the picker shrunk but it still occupies the same space around.

Answer (score 7):

(This actually works and others don't) After much searching this worked:

```
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/dp_datepicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleX="0.7"
    android:scaleY="0.7"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="-30dp"
    android:datePickerMode="spinner"
    />

<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/tp_timepicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleX="0.7"
    android:scaleY="0.7"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="-30dp"
    android:timePickerMode="spinner"
    />
```

The `android:scaleX="0.7"` is what shrinked the visible picker (it works for `DatePicker` and `TimePicker`) and the `android:layout_marginLeft="-30dp"` allowed for the space to be reduced.

Note:
All attempts at using `android:padding="-30dp"` did not work and using `android:layout_margin="-30dp"` (without a side specified) also did not work. Hopefully this helps those who were as lost as me

P.S. Google get your freaking DatePicker API fixed!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using "dp" for the layout width , use percentages in weight to make it smaller.
For android:layout_weight to be effective, put android:layout_width to 0 dip.

`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

`android:layout_weight=".33"`

`android:layout_width="0dip"`

`android:textSize="12sp"`

Comment: Actually when I gave my answer, it used to work. Now as the framework evolved, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

This worked **for me** to fit a date and time picker in a dialogue with a custom layout in landscape mode on a small screen. Set the weightsum of a container (LinarLayout) to 100 and then fill it with widgets adding up to 100 in layout_weight property.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <DatePicker 
                android:id="@+id/dlgDateTimePickerDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TimePicker
                android:id="@+id/dlgDateTimePickerTime"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple scale like this:

`android:scaleY="0.5"
 android:scaleX="0.5"`

to get the half of the size.

And to get a smaller padding, `android:padding="-20dp"`

Looking from the framework the picker may overlap other views, but in the app, it will not.

The padding is going to work perfectly and the buttons also.

Comment: android:padding="-20dp" just doesn't work for TimePicker

Answer (score -2):

**Another solution:**

Put it in a `LinearLayout` and set the height of the `LinearLayout` manually