# calendar cut when orientation change

Tags: android, datepicker

I am trying to display `datepicker` with both portrait and landscape orientation.

I have also add

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

but when I am changing orientation `datepicker` does not show properly look at the screenshorts.

[image]

after change orientation it look like

[image]

anyone have idea about it ??

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37592410/7073808) may help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 DatePickerBuilder().setFragmentManager(childFragmentManager)
            .setYearOptional(true)
            .setDayOfMonth(localDate.dayOfMonth)
            .setMonthOfYear(localDate.monthOfYear - 1)
            .setYear(localDate.year)
            .addDatePickerDialogHandler({ ref, year, month, day ->
                date = LocalDate().withYear(year)
                        .withMonthOfYear(month + 1)
                        .withDayOfMonth(day).toString(OnTimePreferences.dateFormat)
            })
            .setStyleResId(R.style.BetterPickersDialogFragment_Light)
            .show()
```

try this in your code......