# How to customize date picker's width and height in android

Tags: android

Can anybody tell me how to customize the date picker's width and height in android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your layout's *XML* file, change the `android:layout_height` and `android:layout_width` attributes. I am assuming you are currently using either *fill_parent* or *wrap_content* for the values of these attributes, however you can be more specific - defining the exact or scaled pixel value.

For example, `android:layout_width="15dp"` will set the width at a scalable value of 15. You can change 15 to whatever you want. If you want to set a specific pixel size, you can use, for example, `15px`.

Comment: But this doesn't work for all android versions, for example for gingerbread 2.3.3.

Answer (score 48):

The only way I've found to resize it is to simply re-scale the view.  For example, if you only want 80% of the normal size, I would add these attributes:

```
android:scaleX="0.8"
android:scaleY="0.8"
```

Comment: A workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259720/resize-android-datepicker-control

Answer (score 23):

### For DatePicker and TimePicker:

1. *android:scaleX="0.60"* and *android:scaleY="0.60"* 
   Above code will set the visible part of the Date and Time Picker to something like 60% of the total space and
2. *android:layout_marginLeft="-50dp"*, *android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"*, *android:layout_marginRight="-50dp"*, *android:layout_marginBottom="-30dp"* 
   Above code will remove extra spaces around this picker

   > padding="-40dp" doesn't worked for me so I have used margin.

   ```
   <DatePicker
         android:id="@+id/date_picker"
         android:calendarViewShown="false"
         android:layout_height="105dp"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:scaleX="0.60"
         android:scaleY="0.60"
         android:layout_marginLeft="-50dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="-50dp"
         android:layout_marginBottom="-30dp" />

   <TimePicker
         android:id="@+id/time_picker"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="105dp"
         android:scaleX="0.60"
         android:scaleY="0.60"
         android:layout_marginLeft="-55dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="-50dp"
         android:layout_marginBottom="-30dp" />
   ```

Comment: please, provide some information beyond pure code snippet.

Comment: Thanks! After trying tons of other ways the negative margins worked for me!

Comment: OH MY GOD HOW HAVE PEOPLE NOT SEEN THIS THANK YOU

Comment: How did you know how to calculate these margins?

Comment: @Andrew When you add android:scaleX="0.60" and android:scaleY="0.60" , it will reduce the size of picker to 60% of actual size, So remaining 40% will look like empty white border around the picker. So I am using margin to hide that white border.

Comment: I understand that, but I don't understand from where did you get those negative margins? How did you know it should be -50dp, -30dp?

Comment: @Andrew Try to run this code again and again after altering negative margins. Also try to run this code after removing margins, you will know the difference. I am using margins according to my full screen layout, to show the example here. So, it depends upon which layout and design you are targeting to.