# Display DatePicker and TimePicker along side each other in xml

Tags: android, datepicker, timepicker

```
Android Studio 0.6.0
minSdkVersion 10
targetSdkVersion 19
```

Hello,

```
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datePicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:calendarViewShown="false"
    android:scaleX="0.5"
    android:scaleY="0.5"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/timePicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleX="0.5"
    android:scaleY="0.5"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/datePicker"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have the following xml that contains a DatePicker and TimePicker. However, when I test on the device they are too big to fit side by side.

I have tried messing around with the weights and try to make width and height smaller but it still doesn't look right.

[image]

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried your problem and found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674667/how-to-customize-date-pickers-width-and-height-in-android). Though scaling reduced the size of the picker (I tried 0.5) I was unable to place both views on the same layout. This occured due to the padding in the respective pickers. Heres the sample xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <DatePicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        android:scaleX="0.5"
        android:scaleY="0.5" >
    </DatePicker>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TimePicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleX="0.5"
        android:scaleY="0.5" >
    </TimePicker>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following nested layout to achieve your desired visual display. 
Note that the EditText layout shown is just an alternative in case you don't like the scrollable views of date and time.

The attributes like padding, height and width of Date and Time pickers are rigid and so can't be just modified just in the XML. Scaling them makes them just look weird.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="20dp" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/dateScrollView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <DatePicker
                android:id="@+id/datePicker"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/timeScrollView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TimePicker
                android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dateTimeInstructions"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:text="Swipe across Date and Time widgets above to see hidden parts as needed"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="30dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/dateInput"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter Date here"
        android:inputType="date" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/timeInput"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter Time here"
        android:inputType="time" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following on your layouts:

**1.** *(a)* Change your root layout from LinearLayout to RelativeLayout.

**1.** *(b)* Set the following attributes on your 'picker' layouts:

**DatePicker:** `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`

**TimePicker:** `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`

You can interchange the attributes in any order you want for the two pickers.

**2.** Give each of your layouts an ID for reference.

**3.** On any of them, set the following attribute: `android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/OTHER_LAYOUT_ID"`, e.g. assuming you gave the **DatePicker** layout an ID of '`datepicker`', you can set the '`alignBaseline`'attribute on the ***TimePicker*** as;

```
android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/datepicker"
```

This will make both layouts align horizontally on the same line.

**Note:** These attributes work best for elements like **buttons** and other smaller form fields.

Comment: I have updated my question with your answer. However, I have noticed that for layout_alignParentRight, layout_alignParentLeft, and layout_alignBaseline are all invalid for the DatePicker and TimePicker views. Am I doing something wrong? I have also sent a picture of what it looks like. When you adjust the scaling the borders do not adjust. Thanks

Comment: Oops, I forgot to mention that those attributes apply to a RelativeLayout and not LinearLayout. Besides, they work best for elements like buttons but not for Date and Time Picker widgets (especially on small screens). Please check my second solution below.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Actually I tried what you suggested and it didn't look right. I have decided to go with a separate fragment for the date and time.

Comment: @ant2009, have you tried the nested layout I suggested in a separate answer here? It is Ok though if the option you have gone for works fine for you.