# how to override height and width of date picker to fill the parent layout

Tags: android, datepicker

I have an activity contains a date picker. I want to set `DatePicker` fit to the screen. I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674667/how-to-customize-date-pickers-width-and-height-in-android). But which not able to give the result i need.

This is my current code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <DatePicker
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my `DatePicker`:

[image]

I want to make the date picker fill on that green square too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize date picker's width and height in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674667/how-to-customize-date-pickers-width-and-height-in-android)

Comment: Before asking simple question try to google it, [May Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674667/how-to-customize-date-pickers-width-and-height-in-android/34523787#34523787)

Comment: I tried that solution. But which does not strech datepicker to parent layout. @Prem

Comment: Please try it before you comment @MohammedFarhan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this ..

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <DatePicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scaleX="1.1"
        android:scaleY="1.1"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

output like this..

[image]

Comment: this is what i tried, But this is not I need. I want to make that picker scale to its parent layout.

Answer (score 1):

you can meet your requirement by adding gravity for parent like like..

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <DatePicker
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

or else by adding layout_gravity for child as follows

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <DatePicker
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use CalendarView instead of DatePicker