# Date Picker not getting match_parent

Tags: android, datepicker

I am trying to add a `DatePicker` to a view but whatever change it doesn't change its `width`. What I have done is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/common_view_height"
    android:background="@color/orange"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/common_margin_16"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/common_margin_16">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fontFamily="@font/worksansmedium"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/date_selection_heading"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_extra_large" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_date_selection_done"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fontFamily="@font/worksansmedium"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/date_selection_done"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_extra_large" />

</LinearLayout>

<DatePicker
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:headerBackground="@color/orange" />
```

If it is a `TimePicker` it will take the entire screen. Why is that happing?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to override height and width of date picker to fill the parent layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47467550/how-to-override-height-and-width-of-date-picker-to-fill-the-parent-layout)

Comment: @ThomasMary : scaling is not a proper way. it will not work for all device

Comment: Remove **Orientation** in main LinearLayout

Comment: Hi @DKV did you manage to find a proper solution for this?